# Fragments work on tabbed activity although is not called

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I tried to make tabbed fragment for my application but there is a problem. Created tabbed fragment from Android Studio. Made SectionsPagerAdapter. All good and my XML files work correctly, but when it comes to fragment source code my ArchiveALL and ArchiveINS outputs in the same time. I change the tab to ArchiveOUT it doesn't show anything and so on. I couldn't understand that if I am on the first (ArchiveALL) tab why activity calls second ArchiveINS().

This is my SectionPagerAdapter

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by amrah on 2/28/18.
 */

class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> ArchiveList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> titles = new ArrayList<>();
    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title){
        ArchiveList.add(fragment);
        titles.add(title);
    }
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return titles.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return ArchiveList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return ArchiveList.size();
    }
}
```

This is My Tabbed Fragment

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ArchiveInfoFragment extends Fragment {
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;


    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    public ArchiveInfoFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_archive_info, container, false);

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.ArchivePages);
        setupViewAdapter(mViewPager);
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.user_archives);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    }
    private void setupViewAdapter(ViewPager viewPager){
        SectionsPagerAdapter adapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new ArchiveAll(), "ALL");
        adapter.addFragment(new ArchiveINS(), "INS");
        adapter.addFragment(new ArchiveOUTS(), "OUTS");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

}
```

These are my fragments:

ArchiveALL fragment:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class ArchiveAll extends Fragment {

    public ArchiveAll() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_archive_all, container, false);
        System.out.println("it is ALL fragment ");

        return v;


    }

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    }
}

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
```

Here is ArchiveINS fragment:

```
public class ArchiveINS extends Fragment {

    public ArchiveINS() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_arhcive_in, container, false);
        System.out.println("it is INS fragment ");
        return v;
    }

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

And ArchiveOUTS fragment:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class ArchiveOUTS extends Fragment {

    public ArchiveOUTS() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_archive_out, container, false);
        System.out.println("It is OUTS fragment");
        return v;
    }

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    }
}
```

At the end when I open the ArchiveInfoFragment from NavigationDrawer menu it outs :
       I/System.out: it is ALL fragment 
       I/System.out: it is INS fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution. Actually it is not problem, because ViewPager itself loads classes that are in + and - positions. Because of that they are not making program work late. Instead of FragmentPagerAdapter using FragmentStatePagerAdapter will make difference. In FragmentStatePagerAdapter classes are not loading before changing, it loads only the class that user works on.